# Infinite wait loading remote image into BitmapImage() in Background Agent

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a valid URL for a remote JPEG which I'm trying to load in the background.  But I find I never get control back after invoking the `BitmapImage()` constructor.  My question is, should this approach work, or should I pitch it all, load up BcpAsync project from NuGet and start working with WebClient asynch methods?

A sample URL for which it fails is

```
http://image.weather.com/images/maps/current/garden_june_720x486.jpg
```

It is valid.  `.UpdateAsync()` references it from `AppViewModel.Instance`, it's not explicitly referenced here.

Here's the background agent:

```
 protected override async void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            AppViewModel.LoadData();

                await AppViewModel.Instance.RemoteImageProxy.UpdateAsync();
                AppViewModel.Instance.ImageUrl = AppViewModel.Instance.RemoteImageProxy.LocalFileUri;
                AppViewModel.Instance.UpdateCount++;
                PinnedTile.Update();
            }

            AppViewModel.SaveData();
#if DEBUG
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AppViewModel.Instance.BgAgentInterval));
#endif

            NotifyComplete();
        }
```

Here's the invoked method:

```
    public Task<double> UpdateAsync() {

        LastCheckedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        CompletionTask = new TaskCompletionSource<double>();

        // Not usually called on UI thread, not worth optimizing for that case here.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {       //todo determine whether System.Windows.Deployment.Dispatcher can be called from main app, or just bgAgent.
            HelperImageControl = new Image();
            HelperImageControl.Loaded += im_Loaded;
            HelperImageControl.ImageFailed += im_ImageFailed;
            HelperImageControl.ImageOpened += im_ImageOpened;
// breakpoint here
            HelperImageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(SourceUri);
// stepping over the function, control does not return here.  Nor are any of the above events fired. 
        });

        return CompletionTask.Task;                                     // this will be completed in one of the subsequent control events...          
    }
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the output window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call CompletionTask.SetResult(); to return control back to the caller method.

This works (I'm returning 100 in case of successful download because you set the task to return double).

```
TaskCompletionSource<double> CompletionTask;
public Task<double> UpdateAsync()
{
    CompletionTask = new TaskCompletionSource<double>();

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {       
        var HelperImageControl = new Image();

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.ImageOpened += bmp_ImageOpened;
        bmp.ImageFailed += bmp_ImageFailed;
        bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("http://image.weather.com/images/maps/current/garden_june_720x486.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);

        HelperImageControl.Source = bmp;
    });

    return CompletionTask.Task;                                              
}

void bmp_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CompletionTask.SetException(e.ErrorException);
}

void bmp_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CompletionTask.SetResult(100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding my real bug! I was setting event handlers on Image, not BitmapImage.  Why the former don't fire is a puzzle.  
In any case, I was actually calling .SetResult() (in a piece of code I omitted from the sample).